# Ignore and prevent vendored package from being delete with go dep?

Tags: go, dependency-management, godeps, vendoring

I have a bit of an issue, I have a Go project that I depend on (DPkg) and this project has some small dependency on another package (TPkg).

For some reasons which is irrelevant to the question I am not able to build TPkg at the moment however I know that I do not ever use the parts of DPkg that call TPkg so I went ahead and recreated a fake DPkg in my vendor folder.

The issue is that whenever I run `dep ensure`, dep will attempt to handle this package. I have attempted setting an `ignored` constraint on it in my Gopkg.toml but then dep just deletes my code in the vendor folder. I have also tried further adding a `prune.project` constraint to mark TPkg as `unused-packages = false` but that does not prevent dep from deleting the package.

Is there any way that I can tell dep to *ignore TPkg completely* and by that I mean, don't attempt to change it or delete it?

I **know** what this means and how bad it is in terms of issues and maintainability but that is not the question at hand here.

Comment: That's not what [`ignored`](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/Gopkg.toml.html#ignored) is for. This isn't a situation that `dep` is meant to handle.